# How to open Total Commander with specific group of tabs open?

Tags: windows, total-commander

In TotalCommander I have saved the open tabs on the left and on the right windows in a *.tab file.

But I want to put the *.tab file on my desktop and doubleklick it and TC (which is not already running) should open with just those tabs.

And I could have different *.tc files on my desktop then.

I remember this worked before? If so how can I fix it or change a setting?

I know I can open them again from inside TotalCommander but that's not what I am asking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/T` command line parameter of TC. See TC help for more details:

> **/T** Opens the passed dir(s) in new tab(s). Now also works when Total
>   Commander hasn't been open yet.

Just create a .lnk file to the TC on you desktop and setup it to use `/T` with your directories.